# Socket.io, keeping different pages from receiving every message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Sorry about that confusing title but I didn't know how to explain my question, someone please edit it for me accordingly. So i have a website page that receives messages from node server.

```
socket.on('item finished', function(data){
    $('#item'+data).html('finished');
});
```

So basically I'm telling the client that once a item has finished, it must tell that to users.
I'm putting all my js code in script.js and calling it in the pages, so I have the script in all my pages. Whenever I'm on the other pages and the servers emits 'item finished' to the client a message will pop up on console.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of null`

The error isn't quite like that but You get the point, the client is trying to do what it is supposed to do, but I don't want that to happen. 
So is there a way to avoid console errors using the same script file in different pages? What Am I missing?
Thank You!

Comment: Why include a script file that takes care of page-specific functionality in ALL the pages? This is a bad design decision to begin with. Create a separate script file, put only your socket code there and include it only in the relevant pages.

Comment: But my other pages will be linked to the server too. And they are gonna receive messages as well with different functionalities. What do You suggest?

Comment: `socket.on(..//do stuff..)` is some kind of an event listener to the events coming from the server. If you create a new `<script>` file that includes only the `socket.on(..//do stuff..)`  events relevant to your page, then pages that don't include this file will NOT listen to this events, thus there won't be any errors.

Comment: So I must create another script file with a new io.connect() command? Won't this bring any kind of malfunction or conflict on the server?

Comment: You are already doing this anyway, since each page includes the `<script>` tags with the socket code, it attempts to reconnect again and you don't seem to have any issues. Page changes, scripts are loaded again, socket connects and runs your code.

Comment: So this is how it's done on all websites using sicket.io right? Each page opens a connection with the server, this is the normal thing to do?

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Yes, each page that needs to get events from the server opens the socket.io connection to the server.  Yes, that is how it is done.

Comment: @jfriend00 and Nicholas Kyriakides thank you both for your time. I learnt something new and that's never in vain, thank you =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several choices for messages that don't apply to a given page.

1. Separate out the `item finished` message listening code into a separate script so that that script is only loaded and the listener is only active in the pages that you want to actually respond to that message.
2. Leave it the way you have where you are listening to that message in all pages, but in the handler for that message examine the type of page you're in to decide whether you should just ignore the message or do something with it thus avoiding trying to do something with it when it's the wrong kind of page.
3. Bulletproof the code that carries out the action so that it checks to see if the desired element exists before trying to operate on it.  That could look something like this:

Code:

```
// You aren't supposed to have to do this in jQuery, so I'm guessing that
// you aren't actually showing us the right code or error message
// But, this is the general idea of defensive coding
socket.on('item finished', function(data){
    var target = $('#item'+data);
    if (target.length) {
        target.html('finished');
    }
});
```

Comment: I though about suggesting this to him as well, but I don't like seeing unnecessary code on pages where it's not needed - but then again, your 1st point covers this, I guess.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - It's a tradeoff.  It's also a pain to have hundreds of individual script files each for a separate page when 2/3 of them could be combined into a single script file that just detects what type of page it's on and behaves accordingly.  One must draw an appropriate balance.  There is no "pure" answer that is best in all cases.  It is a tradeoff.

Comment: Thank You. Is socket.io designed to handle io.connect command on every site page? I mean, I can write separate scripts for each page and each of those will connect to the server and it won't bring any problems, right? If so, then I have my answer. =]

Comment: @MarcielFonseca - Yes, socket.io expects the connection to be dropped, then re-connected every time you navigate to a new page within a site that is using socket.io for push notifications.

Comment: Agree 100% - But I'd be very careful with your 3rd point since pages might have identically named/id'd elements. If used in combination with any other point then yes, otherwise it looks a bit dangerous.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides then I guess I'll accept his first option, thank You all for your time guys

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides - it's easy to have a site design that uses a particular ID for only one particular use.  If that ID is present, then it means the element should be filled with a particular notification - if not present, then not.  Yes, it takes some coordination to do it that way, but it also can make things really easy if you can be a bit organized like this.  Remember, this is all your site so it's not like you have to worry about conflicts with other people's code.  And you can coin a unique ID name that would never get accidentally used such as `"itemFinishNotificationN"`.